# How to save pdf file in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have a pdf file. I want to write that file in phone memory? Below is the code.
First I am scanning then I am converting the image to pdf, Now I want to save that pdf to phone memory. Please help me.

```
  void onDocumentScanner(BuildContext context) async {
try {
  File scannedDocumentFile;
  var doc = await DocumentScannerFlutter.launchForPdf(context);
  if (doc != null) {
    refreshDownloadedFiles();
    scannedDocumentFile = doc;
    String fileName = basename(scannedDocumentFile.path);
    final directory = (await getExternalStorageDirectory())!.path;
    File saveFilePath = File('$directory/$fileName');
    saveFilePath.openWrite(); //Here I want to save to the file

    print("Path = $fileName");
    Get.toNamed(AppRoutes.viewDownloadedFile,
            arguments: [scannedDocumentFile.path, fileName, folderId])!
        .whenComplete(() {
      refreshFetchedData();
    });
  }
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen the `.openWrite()` method before, but the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/File/openWrite.html) says that it has 2 named arguments FileMode and encoding - try to specify them.
If it won't work, I can only share my solution, with `.writeAsBytes` method.
Instead of `saveFilePath.openWrite()` you can bundle the data first and then save it.

```dart
final byteData = await rootBundle.load(fileName);
await saveFilePath.writeAsBytes(byteData.buffer
          .asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));
```